# How to separately texturize (with different texture files) a 3D model?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I have a 3D file made in Blender and exported to java (.OBJ file), which has his textures separated into some files. Inside this .obj file, it has some fields caled USEMTL and the name of its parts (textures files). However, when I draw it at the screen, he only shows the last USEMTL name.
My question is: How can i proceed to make him read and texturize at the correct way? Without lapping other textures?

#### This is the class that have the .obj loader

```
    public MLoader(String path, Model m) throws IOException {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
            String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith("v ")) {
            float 
            v1 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]), 
            v2 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]), 
            v3 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);

            Vector3f v = new Vector3f (v1, v2, v3);

            m.vertex.add(v);
        } if (line.startsWith("usemtl ")){
            String name = String.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
            m.nameTexture.add(name);
            continue;
        } if (line.startsWith("f ")) {
            float 
            v1 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[0]),
            v2 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[0]),
            v3 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[0]),

            n1 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[1]),
            n2 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[1]),
            n3 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[1]);

            Vector3f
            v = new Vector3f (v1, v2, v3),
            n = new Vector3f (n1, n2, n3);

            m.face.add(new Faces(v, n));
        }if (line.startsWith("vt ")) {
            float 
            vt1 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]), 
            vt2 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);

            Vector2f vt = new Vector2f (vt1, vt2);

            m.vertexTexture.add(vt);
        } 
    }
}
```

As you can see, I created a IF statement, just to get this usemtl stuff (that is inside .obj file) - the texture names (which are into separate files) just to see if I could bind them individually. But I'm having trouble to do that (perhaps, logic isn't in my side). How to proceed?

Other classes:

#### Texture Class

```
public class Textures {
    public Texture[] tx;

    public void setNumTex(int i) {
        tx = new Texture[i];
    }

    public void setTexture(String format, String name, int i) {
        try {
            tx[i] = TextureLoader.getTexture(format, new FileInputStream(new File("res/Textures/" + name + format)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void texturing(Vector2f ft1, Vector2f ft2, int indexx) {
        for (int i=0; i<indexx; i++) {
            tx[i].bind();
        }
        glTexCoord2f(ft1.x, ft1.y);
        glTexCoord2f(ft2.x, ft2.y);
    }
}
```

#### Render Class

```
public class Renderer {
    Model m;

    public void loadContent(String objPath) {
        //Everithing that is loading is been putting here
        m = Model.getModel("res/Models/" + objPath);

        m.loadTex();
    }

    public void render() {
        glEnable(GL_SMOOTH);

        m.renderModel();
    }
}
```

#### Model Class

```
public class Model {
    Textures tx;

    List<Vector3f> vertex, norms;
    List<Vector2f> vertexTexture;
    List<Faces> face;
    List<String> nameTexture;
    String name[];

    private int numTex = 0;

    Vector2f 
    t1 = new Vector2f(), t2 = new Vector2f();

    Vector3f
    v1 = new Vector3f(), v2 = new Vector3f(), v3 = new Vector3f(),
    n1 = new Vector3f(), n2 = new Vector3f(), n3 = new Vector3f(),

    public Model(String path)throws 
    LWJGLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        vertex = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        norms = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        vertexTexture = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
        face = new ArrayList<Faces>();
        nameTexture = new ArrayList<String>();

        tx = new Textures();

        new MLoader(path, this);
    }

    public static Model getModel(String path, Vector3f position, Vector3f rotation) {
        try {
            return new Model(path, position, rotation);
        } catch (LWJGLException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void loadTex() {
        name = new String[nameTexture.toArray().length];
        tx.setNumTex(nameTexture.toArray().length);

        for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++) {
            name[i] = nameTexture.get(i);
            numTex += 1;

            tx.setTexture(".TGA", name[i], i);
        }
    }

    public void renderModel() {
        glPushMatrix();
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        {
            for (Faces f : face) {
                v1 = vertex.get((int) f.v.x - 1);
                v2 = vertex.get((int) f.v.y - 1);
                v3 = vertex.get((int) f.v.z - 1);
                n1 = vertex.get((int) f.n.x - 1);
                n2 = vertex.get((int) f.n.y - 1);
                n3 = vertex.get((int) f.n.z - 1);
                t1 = vertexTexture.get((int) f.n.x - 1); //
                t2 = vertexTexture.get((int) f.n.y - 1); // 

                //Vertexes
                glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y-3.4f, v1.z-0.53f);
                glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y-3.4f, v2.z-0.53f);
                glVertex3f(v3.x, v3.y-3.4f, v3.z-0.53f);

                //Normals
                glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y-3.4f, n1.z-0.53f);
                glNormal3f(n2.x, n2.y-3.4f, n2.z-0.53f);
                glNormal3f(n3.x, n3.y-3.4f, n3.z-0.53f);

                //Texture
                tx.texturing(t1, t2, numTex);
                //tx.texturing(n1, n2, n3);             
            }
        }
        glEnd();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not put any code as your question is pretty complex for a 2 line solution.But here how it is usually works in a simple 3D engine.Multiple texturing of a mesh implies that the mesh is broken into 2 or more sub-meshes.I am not blender specialist but I am sure it is capable of exporting the mesh with its sub-mesh tree just like Autodesk 3D studio max.Now,when you import such a mesh into your program you should be able to parse all those sub-meshes into separate entities.Every such a sub-mesh has its own vertices,texture coordinates and normals. When issuing the draw call you would iterate over all the sub-meshes one by one and draw each of them in its own draw call.So on on each draw call you should be able also to attach a unique texture to be used for that specific sub-mesh.That's all.Now it is up to you how to design such a system.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, thanks for the help. If I fix the problem, I'll post what I did to solve.
By the way, I've seen some archives on gitHub, like this: "https://github.com/integeruser/jgltut", and I'm trying to study it.
By the way, if you have some tutorial of Multi Texturing (simple, or just explaning it) I'd appreciate that, and if you don't, do not worry, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I discovered what was the problem.
Here's the solution: At the class MLoader, I had just to put a "distinguisher" at the "usemtl" part. With it, when he is at the "F SECTION", when he returns and adds to "faceArray" thing the face, he just adds more then he needs.

Example:

```
face.add(1, 2, 3);
faceArray.add(face); //Assuming that the face has his 1, 2, 3 thing
```

when he goes again to the "f" if, he adds

```
face.add(4, 5, 6);
faceArray.add(face); //But, this time, when he adds the face, it already had 1, 2, 3, 

//so, he's with '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6' into him
```

Here's the changse i've made (just the changes):

#### Class MLoader:

```
public MLoader(String path, Model m) throws IOException {
...
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            ...
            } if (line.contains("g ")) {
                index = 0;
            } if (line.startsWith("usemtl ") && index == 0){
                String name = String.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);   
                m.nameTexture.add(name);
                m.faceArray.add(m.face);

                m.face = new ArrayList<Faces>();
                index = 1;
            } if (line.contains("f ") && index == 1) {
                ...
            }
```

#### Class Model:

```
int numTex = 0;
List<List <Faces>> faceArray;
...

public void loadTex() {
    for (String n : nameTexture) {
        tx.loadTexture("TGA", n);
        numTex ++;
    }
}
...

public void renderModel() {
...
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        for (int i = 0; i < numTex; i++) {
            tx.tx.get(i).bind();

            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            {
                for (Faces f : faceArray.get(i)) {              
                    ...
                    }
                }
                glEnd();
            }
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            ...
    }
```